# Rails query for all questions in tournaments that a user participates in

Tags: beginner, ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record, join

I'm new to rails and this is the situation I'm in: I have a `User` model that has many tournaments, a `Tournament` has many users and questions and a `Question` belongs to a tournament. I'm trying to write a query for all questions that are in tournaments the user is a part of, for example if we have the user A in tournament 1 which has questions alpha, beta, gamma and another tournament 2 with questions omega and delta, I want to display alpha, beta and gamma. So far this is what I've come up with:

```
def user_questions
  first_questions = scope.joins(:tournament)\
                         .merge(Tournament.where(id: user.tournaments.first.id))
  user.tournaments.each do |tournament|
    current_questions = scope.joins(:tournament)\
                             .merge(Tournament.where(id: tournament.id))
    first_questions = first_questions.or(current_questions)
  end

  first_questions
end
```

(Imagine scope is `Question`) Now this works but even I can see this code isn't that good, to put it mildly. I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: so user `has_many :tournaments` and tournament `has_many :questions`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Procede with random chars to fill minimum comment length req

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so based on what your said your associations are you can do

```
class User
  has_many :tournaments
  has_many :questions, through: :tournaments
end

u = User.first
questions = u.questions
```

If you don't want that for some reason you can do

```
class User
  has_many :tournaments
end

class Question
  belongs_to :tournament
end

u = User.first
questions = Question.where(tournament_id: u.tournament_ids)
```

Rails will convert that into a `where tournament_id in (?)` sql statement

Comment: I'll have to discuss it with my mentor if it's ok to add such a link to the model.

Comment: @Robert have added another option for you, but might need some refinement based on how questions relate to users

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't know you could do plural id-s :D thanks a lot